# Session management issue

Tags: javascript, session, jakarta-ee

How to manage sessions in a Java EE web application where a user logs in for writing an exam?

And how to manage sessions where there is a break in the session and a user needs to continue his exam from where there is a break. What type of session management needs to be used?

Answer (score 3):

You'd store something in a user record indicating where they are in the test--not really session-management-specific, since their session would go away when they log out or it times out. When they log back in you retrieve that information from their database info.